# Ninja Forms 3 - Pre-select radio button based on URL variable

Tags: ninja-forms

A WordPress page with the Ninja Form (v3) has a radio-list, and I need to have a specific radio-button pre-selected based on a URL variable passed in:
e.g. http://the-website.com/ninja-form-page/?tour=2 would result in the second radio button in the list (with a value=2) to be pre-selected when the form page loads.

This was easily accomplished in Ninja-Forms v2x with a filter in the functions.php that checks for the URL variable and loops through the form-field labels for a match (http://www.wpmusketeer.com/pre-populate-ninja-forms-fields-from-url-parameters/). But I can't figure out a solution in v3x. It seems that the form fields render quite differently, and there is no API section in the v3x documentation like there was in v2x.

Answer (score 2):

Use "ninja_forms_render_default_value" filter:

```
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'my_ninja_forms_pre_populate', 10, 3 );
function my_ninja_forms_pre_populate( $default_value, $field_type, $field_settings ){
    if( 'field_key' == $field_settings[ 'key' ] ){
        $default_value = 2;
    }
    return $default_value;
}
```

Of course - register your URL variable as "query_vars"